# Why is my function calculating wrong distance between 2 points

Tags: python, location, distance

I have a dataframe that summarizes neighborhoods and cafes in these neighborhoods together with their locations, called Final. And generated random location points, each 100 meters apart. I would like now to calculate the distance between data points (cafes) in the Final dataframe and the closest location that was randomly generated.

I am trying to clone code in [this notebook (Code block number 92-96)](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/cocl.us/coursera_capstone_notebook#Table-of-contents)

I think the problem is in my initial dataframe. But I do not know what I should do with the dataframe to make this work.

The events variable in the code below stores the Final dataframe turned into a dictionary (because in the code I am trying to clone they used dictionary). However, in my function find_nearest_restaurant the res[4] does not take latitude and longitude... Not sure what to do with it.

Final dataframe[This is how dataframe looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHp4y.png)

I am trying the following code for this:

```py
def find_nearest_restaurant(x, y, events):
    d_min = 100000
    for res in events:
        res_x = res[4]; res_y = res[5]
        d = calc_xy_distance(x, y, res_x, res_y)
        if d<=d_min:
            d_min = d
    return d_min


def lonlat_to_xy(lon, lat):
    proj_latlon = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong',datum='WGS84')
    proj_xy = pyproj.Proj(proj="utm", zone=33, datum='WGS84')
    xy = pyproj.transform(proj_latlon, proj_xy, lon, lat)
    return xy[0], xy[2]


events = Final.to_dict()
Kralingen_center = [51.928263, 4.50344]
Kr_center_x, Kr_center_y = lonlat_to_xy(Kralingen_center[2], Kralingen_center[0]) 
Centrum_Center = [51.922909, 4.47059]
k = math.sqrt(3) / 2 # Vertical offset for hexagonal grid cells
x_step = 100
y_step = 100 * k 
roi_x_min = Kr_center_x - 2000
roi_y_max = Kr_center_y + 1000
roi_center_x = roi_x_min + 2000
roi_center_y = roi_y_max - 2500
roi_y_min = roi_center_y - 2500


def xy_to_lonlat(x, y):
    proj_latlon = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong',datum='WGS84')
    proj_xy = pyproj.Proj(proj="utm", zone=33, datum='WGS84')
    lonlat = pyproj.transform(proj_xy, proj_latlon, x, y)
    return lonlat[0], lonlat[2]


def calc_xy_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)


roi_latitudes = []
roi_longitudes = []
roi_xs = []
roi_ys = []

for i in range(0, int(51/k)):
    y = roi_y_min + i * y_step
    x_offset = 50 if i%2==0 else 0
    for j in range(0, 51):
        x = roi_x_min + j * x_step + x_offset
        d = calc_xy_distance(Kr_center_x, Kr_center_y, x, y)
        if (d <= 2001):
            lon, lat = xy_to_lonlat(x, y)
            roi_latitudes.append(lat)
            roi_longitudes.append(lon)
            roi_xs.append(x)
            roi_ys.append(y)


print(len(roi_latitudes), 'candidate points generated.')


def find_nearest_restaurant(x, y, events):
    d_min = 100000
    for res in events:
        res_x = res[4]; res_y = res[5]
        d = calc_xy_distance(x, y, res_x, res_y)
        if d<=d_min:
            d_min = d
    return d_min
```

I would like to receive a dataframe with:

```py
df_roi_locations = pd.DataFrame({'Latitude':roi_latitudes,
                                 'Longitude':roi_longitudes,
                                 'X':roi_xs,
                                 'Y':roi_ys,
                                 'Distance to restaurant':roi_kr_distances})
```

`roi_kr_distances` is just a result of running `find_nearest_restaurant` function and appending it to an empty list.

But the code gives me an error:

```
<ipython-input-70-b6a8fa5871aa> in find_nearest_restaurant(x, y, events)
     53     for res in events:
     54         res_x = res[3]; res_y = res[4]
---> 55         d = calc_xy_distance(x, y, res_x, res_y)
     56         if d<=d_min:
     57             d_min = d

<ipython-input-70-b6a8fa5871aa> in calc_xy_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)
     26 
     27 def calc_xy_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
---> 28     dx = x2 - x1
     29     dy = y2 - y1
     30     return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

Comment: It looks like you need to coerce the datatype of either x2 or x1 in your function (or dataframe) to a numerical one (e.g. float)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say from the example code you provided, because I don't know what is being stored inside of the events variable, but from your error it just looks like you have two data types (string, and Float) and you're trying to perform the subtraction on them which isn't allowed in python.

This is the only thing suggest trying, which is to try and convert your parameters to floats.

```
def calc_xy_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dx = float(x2) - float(x1)
    dy = float(y2) - float(y1)
    return math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now, it tells me I cannot convert string 'g' to float. So, the res[4] probably takes the wrong value..